# How can I add a custom attribute to each row of a MUI DataGrid (pro) table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I need to add an attribute 'data-testid' to each row of a table, but I cannot figure out how to do so using MUI DataGrid Pro. Adding classNames is possible (using [getRowClassName](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/)), but adding an attribute, along with its value (something like 'data-testid='row-{key}', seems more complicated.

Someone already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804822/how-can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-mui-datagrid-column-header), but for columns - the solution cannot seem to be applicable to rows.

I tried using getRowClassName and [slotProps](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/), with no success. I also tried to find workarounds and move the attribute to the cell level with renderCell() but I really need the attribute to be at the row level.

Thanks!

Comment: MUI is already adding both a `data-id` attribute and a `data-rowindex` attribute to each row. You should be able to leverage those for testing without needing to add a separate `data-testid` attribute.

Comment: @RyanCogswell You're right, it is possible indeed, but I would love to keep it in line with the rest of the codebase (using data-testid) and not create a custom testing command for these...

Comment: @RyanCogswell care to provide an example of what you are talking about?